# Handling asynchronous data between services and components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise, observable

I am passing the latitude and longitude to a service from a component. And after doing some work in the service, I want to pass the value in `isOnsite`to my component. Depending on that value, I want to bring up another page.

My problem:

When I get the returned value in the component, it is only `undefined` as the service runs asynchronously. What can I change in my code to get the correct value in my component? Below is my code. (isAtSite computes some math and returns a boolean).

Also is there a way to push to the page stack from the service?

**location.service.ts**

```
getDeviceCoords(map, destLat, destLng) {

this.mapInstance = map;
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((pos) => {

  new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);   
  let deviceLat = pos.coords.latitude;
  let deviceLng = pos.coords.longitude;

  let isOnSite = this.isAtSite(deviceLat, deviceLng, destLat, destLng);
  return isOnSite;

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
}
```

**map.component.ts**

```
getDeviceCoords(){

let isOnSite = this.geolocationProvider.getDeviceCoords(this.map, this.lat, this.lng); 
console.log("isOnSite (map.ts) =>" + isOnSite);  //undefined. Should be boolean 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined because you didnt return anything from the function `getDeviceCoords(map, destLat, destLng)` (that equals to return `undefined)`

`return isOnSite` inside `getDeviceCoords` really returns not from `getDeviceCoords`, but from callback passed to `then` - `(pos) => {}`

So, first of all, you must return promise from `getDeviceCoords`:

```
getDeviceCoords(map, destLat, destLng) {

  this.mapInstance = map;
  return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(...your code);
}
```

And then in your component you can use it like

```
getDeviceCoords() {
  this.geolocationProvider.getDeviceCoords(this.map,this.lat, this.lng)
  .then(isOnSite => // your value can be accessed here);
}
```